# C++ Combine strings for 'system' function error

Tags: c++

I'm having this c++ error which I can't really understand(I'm new to c++). I think the code should work, but it does not. So I came to ask for help.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Cpy{
  public:
    string exc;
     void cpy(string pyfile){
     exc = "python" + pyfile;
     system(exc);
    }
};

int main(){
  Cpy ex;
  ex.cpy("example.py");
```

}

Comment: You forgot to tell us the error.

Comment: `system` doesn't take a `std::string` parameter. You would notice this if you looked it up.

Comment: ^ or read the compiler error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::system()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) expects its string in the form of a pointer to a null-terminated array of `char`. You cannot hand it an `std::string` directly. You can use the [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method of `std::string` to get a pointer to a null-terminated version of the `std::string`'s contents:

```
system(exc.c_str());
```

Also, you most likely forgot to put a space between `"python"` and your argument.

Apart from that, `exc` should most likely be a local variable inside your `cpy()` method rather than a member of the class `Cpy`.

Instead of passing an `std::string` object by value I'd consider to rather pass the `pyfile` argument to `cpy()` in form of an [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) (if your compiler supports C++17) or a plain `const char*`. Furthermore, if you want to build more complex strings, you might want to consider using an [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) instead of just concatenating string objects:

```
void cpy(string_view pyfile)
{
    ostringstream cmd;
    cmd << "python " << pyfile;
    system(exc.str().c_str());
}
```

For just two strings, it won't matter. But if you want to concatenate many more strings or, e.g., also incorporate numbers and other stuff that needs formatting into your string, using a stringstream would generally seem to be a better idea.